# In object oriented php class , what is meant by $this->name = $name?

Tags: php, class, this

```
class User {

  public $name;

  public function __construct($name) {
    $this->name = $name;
  }

  public function sayHi() {
    echo "Hi, I am $this->name!";
  }
}
```

Can someone explain to me word by word, what is meant by $this->name=$name?
I keep thinking like, $this goes into(hence the -> sign) name which is (hence the = sign) $name defined beforehand.
Also I dont see the need of that function?

Could just go like this :

```
class User {

  public $name;

  public function sayHi() {
    echo "Hi, I am $name!";
  }
}
```

I'm out of idea thinking about this .. thanks in advance.

Comment: `$this->name` refers to the class property `$name`. `$name`, the `__construct` parameter is just a variable. So, you're assigning the `__construct` parameter `$name` to the class property `$name`. `$this` refers to the current class. Do note that the `__construct` parameter `$name` could have had any other name, again, it's just a parameter or a simple variable, where as `$this->name` refers to the class property name. [Read more](http://php.net/manual/ro/language.oop5.properties.php)

Comment: Thank You a million! wow this really helps to clear up my understanding . Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are creating a new instance of the class `User` with the `__construct` parameter `$name`, by `$this->name`it is set to the `$name` property of the class. In your second example `$name` does not get any value because you are nowhere assigning any value to it.

You could also have it like this for better understanding:

```
class User {

  public $nameProperty;

  public function __construct($name) {
    $this->nameProperty = $name;
  }

  public function sayHi() {
    echo "Hi, I am $this->nameProperty!";
  }
}
```

`$this` refers to the class you are currently in. So when you create a new class of `User`, you can pass a name by using the `$name` parameter. This parameter then gets assigned to the `$nameProperty` and in your method `sayHi()` you would then echo the assigned name.

Comment: Thanks, really helps alot :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class User {

   public $name; //declare a public property

   public function __construct($name) {
      $this->name = $name; 
     /* at the time of object creation u have to send the value & that value will be store into a public property which will be available through out the class. like $obj = new User('Harry'); Now this will be set in $this->name & it is available inside any method without declaration.

     */
   }

   public function sayHi() {
     echo "Hi, I am $this->name!"; //$this->name is available here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the context of a class method, when you want to access the class properties, you have to use **$this->property**. Without *$this*, you are actually accessing a variable in the scope of the method, which in your case, is the parameter *$name*.

The function **__construct()** is the **constructor** for your class object. So if you would instantiate an object, you would execute the code inside the constructor. Example:

```
$user = new User("John"); // you are actually calling the __construct method here
echo $user->name; // John
```

Hope that enlightens you.

Comment: Thanks! I was actually wondering about that too Rax!. Thanks again